# Getting errors not reading data from database in Joomla v3

Tags: php, joomla

I'm getting errors by Joomla v3 from my `helper.php` file and my `mod_ip_address_map.php` file.

In my `helper.php` file the errors are coming from this part:

```
function getIPData() {
    $db = JFactory::getDbo();
    $query = $db->getQuery(true);

    $query->select($db->quoteName(['ip_address', 'latitude', 'longitude']))
          ->from($db->quoteName('#__ip_data'));

    $db->setQuery($query);
    $results = $db->loadResult();

    $data = array();
    foreach ($results as $row) {
        $data[] = array(
            'ip_address' => $row['ip_address'],
            'latitude' => $row['latitude'],
            'longitude' => $row['longitude']
        );
    }

    return $data;
}
```

This is where the errors are reported by Joomla v3.

Error starts here:

```
 'ip_address' => $row['ip_address'],
```

In my `mod_ip_address_map.php` file the error is in this part:

```
// Load the module parameters
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select($db->quoteName('params'))
      ->from($db->quoteName('#__modules'))
      ->where($db->quoteName('module') . ' = ' . $db->quote('mod_ip_address_map'))
      ->where($db->quoteName('published') . ' >= 1')
      ->where($db->quoteName('client_id') . ' = ' . (int) $app->getClientId())
      ->setLimit(1);

$db->setQuery($query);
$params = $db->loadObject()->params;

// Output the module HTML
echo mod_ip_address_map($params);
```

This is where the error is reported by Joomla v3.
Error is here:

```
echo mod_ip_address_map($params);
```

Here is the error message:

> 0 - Call to undefined function mod_ip_address_map()

Also, the 'params' data, api_key, is not being entered into the database

Comment: The one thing you've forgotten to tell us is the actual error message(s) and stack trace(s) :-)

Comment: mysqli is not a database

Comment: Sorry, I am new to this. Here is the error message:

0 - Call to undefined function mod_ip_address_map()

Also, the 'params' data, api_key, is not being entered into the database.

Comment: No problem. It's very hard to fix errors when you don't know what they are! P.S. You need to [edit] your question when you have important info, it doesn't belong in the comments (this isn't a forum or chatroom). I did it for you this time :-).

Comment: In your first snippet, `loadResult()` returns a single, value; it does not return an array of associative arrays.  You want [`loadAssocList()`](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A12352+loadassoclist)  Please ask all of your Joomla questions on [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.